# set input type key value from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everyone i am trying to set key value for input type jquery but i am getting this function.upload.js?v=1.x:26 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list really tried everything but could not find the solution

```
 form.append('<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="'s3Policy['inputs']['policy']'" />');
```

here s3Policy['inputs'] is an array. please help me solving this error. Sorry for asking such a basic question.

Comment: you can't mix quotes like that, you need to clean up your syntax. or perhaps ask the question in a way that explains what you want, but are not sure how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with the right unwrap

```
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="' + s3Policy["inputs"]["policy"] + '" />');
//                                               here ^^^^^^                 and here ^^^^^^
```

Comment: happy coding @NiteshMishra

Answer (score 2):

You missed the concatenation from your value attribute

Here is the solution:

```
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="'+ s3Policy['inputs']['policy'] +'" />');
```